# Putting an image inside another image in Android

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout, nine-patch

I am trying to achieve the following screenshot in android.

[image]

To get Round Image I have Round Image Library from here:

https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView

So I tried the following code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/marker"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<com.ylg.RoundImageView
        android:id="@+id/profilePhoto"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:src="@drawable/profilepic" />
```

but I ended up getting error:

```
 NOTE: This project contains Java compilation errors, which can cause rendering failures for  custom views. Fix compilation problems first.

 Exception raised during rendering: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

I need 9 patch to my marker image: Which I did below:

[image]

What could be wrong here. How do I achieve the abouve screenshot in my layout xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just play with margin to fit it exactly:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="130dip"
        android:layout_height="130dip"
        android:background="@drawable/bg" >

        <com.example.mmlooloo.RoundedImageView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="90dip"
            android:layout_height="90dip"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/profile"
            app:border_color="#0000FF"
            app:border_width="2dip"
            app:corner_radius="80dip" 
            app:oval="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Default screen margins, per the Android Design guidelines. -->
    <dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">16dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">16dp</dimen>

</resources>
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved the issue for me. I added few changed to my nine path pic to fit the picture properly. Everything is working fine now..

Answer (score 3):

Can't you use `FrameLayout` like this?

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.testproject.MainActivity" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/bg" >
    </ImageView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/overlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

I used your border image as `@drawable/bg` and I am getting this output:

[image]

In your case, image of user will be smaller than border image, so that should fit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ Dhruti: How come it is not working for me? What could be wrong here? Also match_parent is a issue for me. I get a very big image as output

Comment: Image size must be large. :/

Comment: @ Dhruti - I reduced the size. I still have the same problem :(

Comment: @TheDevMan then no idea. But I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886719/putting-an-image-inside-another-image-in-android/25904299#25904299) is what you want.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the  background of ImageView to a drawable(xml) resource containing the background image and set the ImageView src to your desired picture. This should solve your problem.

**EDIT**

Try this code

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_chatUserImg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="@drawable/bb"
        android:paddingBottom="40.0dip"
        android:paddingTop="10.0dip"
        android:paddingRight="10.0dip"
        android:paddingLeft="10.0dip"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_smiley"/>
```

where 'bb' is the backgournd white image and src contains the actual image tat is displayed over it.

[image]

I have adjusted my padding accordingly.If the image size varies then wrap the imageview in another LinearLayout and set the background and padding to it and position the image view inside it and fix the size so it always remains inside the white border

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: @ Panther: The issue here is that I want my profile photo to be rounded and hence I am calling RoundImageView library. If I use background I can't achieve what is required.